# Links on original webpage missing after parsing with beautiful soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Please excuse me if my explanation seems elementary. I'm new to both python and beautiful soup.

I'm trying to extract data from the following website :

https://valor.militarytimes.com/award/5?page=1

I want to extract the links that correspond to each of the 24 medal recipients on the website. I can see from Firefox inspector that they all have the word 'hero' in their links. However, when I use beautiful soup to parse the website, these links do not appear.

I have tried using the standard html parser as well as the html5lib parser but none of them show the links corresponding to these medal recipients.

```
page = requests.get('https://valor.militarytimes.com/award/5?page=1')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html5lib")
for idx, link in enumerate(soup.find_all('a', href = True)):
        print(link)
```

The above code finds only some of the links on the original website, and in particular, there are no links corresponding to the medal recipients.  Even running soup.prettify() shows that these links are not in the parsed text.

I hope to have a simple code that can extract the links for the 24 medal recipients on this website.

Comment: Those elements are loaded using JavaScript, they're not part of the response you get from the server. You'll have to look into web scraping tools that render the page in a browser-like environment and allow JS requests.

Comment: So try something like this? 

http://stanford.edu/~mgorkove/cgi-bin/rpython_tutorials/Scraping_a_Webpage_Rendered_by_Javascript_Using_Python.php

Comment: Yes, selenium can drive a real browser for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid using selenium, there is a simple way to get the data you require. The page loads the data by sending a post requests to he following url,

```
https://valor.militarytimes.com/api/awards/5?page=1
```

This sends a `json` response which is then used to populate the page using JavaScript. All you have to do is send the same request using python-requests and then get the data out of the json response.

```
import requests
r=requests.post('https://valor.militarytimes.com/api/awards/5?page=1')
for item in r.json()['data']:
    name=item['recipient']['name']
    url='https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/'+str(item['recipient']['id'])
    print(name,url)
```

Output:

```
EUGENE MCCARLEY https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/500963
TIMOTHY KEENAN https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/500962
JOHN THOMPSON https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/500961
WALTER BORDEN https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/500941
WILLIAM ROSE https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/94465
YUKITAKA MIZUTARI https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/94175
ALBERT MARTIN https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/92498
FRANCIS CODY https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/500944
JAMES O'KEEFFE https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/500943
PHILLIP FLEMING https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/500942
JOHN WANAMAKER https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/314466
ROBERT CHILSON https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/102316
CHRISTOPHER NELMS https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/89255
SAMUEL BARNETT https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/71533
ANDREW BYERS https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/500938
ANDREW RUSSELL https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/500937
****** CALDWELL https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/500935
****** WALWRATH https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/500934
****** MADSEN https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/500933
****** NELSON https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/500932
WILLIAM SOUKUP https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/500931
BENJAMIN WILSON https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/500930
ANDREW MARCKESANO https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/500929
WAYNE KUNZ https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/500927
```

I have fetched the name as well. You can just get the link if you require only that.

**Edit**

To get urls from multiple pages, use this code

```
import requests
list_of_urls=[]
last_page=9 #replace this with your last page
for i in range(1,last_page+1):
    r=requests.post('https://valor.militarytimes.com/api/awards/5?page={}'.format(i))
    for item in r.json()['data']:
        url='https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/'+str(item['recipient']['id'])
        list_of_urls.append(url)
print(list_of_urls)
```

Output:

```
['https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/500963', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/500962', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/500961', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/500941', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/94465', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/94175', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/92498', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/500944', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/500943', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/500942', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/314466', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/102316', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/89255', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/71533', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/500938', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/500937', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/500935', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/500934', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/500933', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/500932', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/500931', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/500930', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/500929', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/500927', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/500926', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/500925', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/500924', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/500923', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/500922', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/500921', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/500920', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/500919', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/500918', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/500917', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/500916', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/500915', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/500914', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/500913', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/500912', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/500911', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/500910', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/500909', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/500908', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/500907', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/500906', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/500905', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/500904', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/500903', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/500902', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/500901', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/500900', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/500899', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/500898', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/500897', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/500896', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/500895', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/500894', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/500893', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/500892', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/500891', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/500890', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/500889', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/500888', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/29160', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/106931', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/106375', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/94936', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/94928', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/94927', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/94926', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/94923', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/94777', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/94769', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/94711', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/94644', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/94571', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/94570', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/94494', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/94468', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/94454', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/94388', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/94358', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/94279', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/94275', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/94253', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/94251', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/94223', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/94222', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/94217', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/94211', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/94210', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/94195', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/94194', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/94173', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/94168', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/94055', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/93916', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/93847', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/93780', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/93779', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/93775', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/93774', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/93733', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/93722', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/93706', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/93551', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/93435', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/93407', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/93374', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/93277', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/93243', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/93193', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/92989', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/92972', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/92958', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/93923', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/90130', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/90128', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/89704', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/89703', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/89702', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/89701', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/89698', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/89673', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/89661', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/90127', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/89535', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/89493', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/89406', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/89405', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/89404', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/89261', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/89259', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/88805', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/88803', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/88789', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/88770', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/88766', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/88765', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/88719', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/88680', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/88679', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/88678', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/88658', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/88657', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/88616', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/88578', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/88551', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/88445', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/88366', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/88365', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/88045', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/88044', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/88013', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/88012', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/87986', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/87918', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/87909', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/87898', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/87830', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/88570', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/88568', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/88239', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/87792', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/87782', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/87677', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/87655', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/87523', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/87460', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/87292', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/87291', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/87288', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/87283', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/87282', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/87281', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/87280', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/87279', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/87272', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/86875', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/86811', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/86451', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/86077', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/86076', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/85994', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/86005', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/6190', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/5022', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/500877', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/500851', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/500844', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/500843', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/500842', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/500841', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/500840', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/500839', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/500838', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/500837', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/500836', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/500835', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/500834', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/500833', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/500832', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/500831', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/500830', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/500829', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/500827', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/500826', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/500817', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/500816', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/500815', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/500813', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/500808', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/401188', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/401185', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/89851', 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/89846']
```

Comment: @QHarr I will include the last page part. But, don't delete your answer, I think it may be useful to the OP to see different approaches.

Comment: This was extremely helpful. And you're right that what I was looking for was precisely to download urls from a range of pages. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use both selenium webdriver & beautiful soup

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/award/5?page=1'
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('window-size=1920x1080');
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(10)
page=driver.page_source
soup=BeautifulSoup(page,'lxml')
items = soup.select('a',href=True)
hero=[]
for item in items:
   if 'hero' in item['href']:
       print(item['href'])
       hero.append(item['href'])

print(hero)
```

Output:

```
/hero/500963
/hero/500962
/hero/500961
/hero/500941
/hero/94465
/hero/94175
/hero/92498
/hero/500944
/hero/500943
/hero/500942
/hero/314466
/hero/102316
/hero/89255
/hero/71533
/hero/500938
/hero/500937
/hero/500935
/hero/500934
/hero/500933
/hero/500932
/hero/500931
/hero/500930
/hero/500929
/hero/500927


['/hero/500963', '/hero/500962', '/hero/500961', '/hero/500941', '/hero/94465', '/hero/94175', '/hero/92498', '/hero/500944', '/hero/500943', '/hero/500942', '/hero/314466', '/hero/102316', '/hero/89255', '/hero/71533', '/hero/500938', '/hero/500937', '/hero/500935', '/hero/500934', '/hero/500933', '/hero/500932', '/hero/500931', '/hero/500930', '/hero/500929', '/hero/500927']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make POST requests to API to retrieve json containing the ids for each recipient you can concatenate onto a base url to give the full url for each recipient. The json contains the url of the last page so you can determine the end point for a subsequent loop over all pages.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

baseUrl = 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/hero/'
url = 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/api/awards/5?page=1'
headers = {

  'Accept' : 'application/json, text/plain, */*' ,
  'Referer' : 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/award/5?page=1',
  'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0'    
}

info = requests.post(url, headers = headers, data = '').json()
urls = [baseUrl + str(item['recipient']['id']) for item in info['data']]   #page 1
linksInfo = info['links']
firstLink = linksInfo['first']
lastLink = linksInfo['last']
lastPage = lastLink.replace('https://valor.militarytimes.com/api/awards/5?page=','')
print('last page = ' + lastPage)
print(urls)
```

I had been testing with retrieving all results and noticed you would need potentially back off and retry.

You can build the additional urls as follows:

```
if lastPage > 1:
        for page in range(2, lastPage + 1):
            url = 'https://valor.militarytimes.com/api/awards/5?page={}'.format(page)
```